# Why can't I create a Servlet in an existing Maven Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets

I checked out an existing Maven Project with the following directory structure:

[image: directory structure]

I'm trying to create a servlet class in `ConfigFileInput.java`:

[image: servlet code]

As you can see, it doesn't recognize the servlet imports.

However, when I create a web project outside of my existing Maven Project, it works just fine. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, this stuff is pretty confusing. I would appreciate some help/suggestions.

Comment: Right-click your project, select Build Path. In Libraries tab, do you see Maven Dependencies? If so, is `servlet-api` a dependency in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I added it just now from the answer below, it removed all the errors except for: `javax.servlet.annotation`

Comment: The package `javax.servlet.annotation` is for servlet 3.0. Check [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1) for the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `servlet-api` as dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<project>
.
.

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
.
.
</project>
```

with the correct version your project is using

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to work for me. How do I figure out which version of servlet-api my project is using?

Comment: if you are attempting to use servlet  3.0 features for instance annotation based servlet etc.. you can choose 3.0 if you are using any other framework which are compatible with just some version of servlet api then use that version, generally these are the deciding factors

Comment: Don't forget to set the `<scope>` to `provided` if you are running it on a local tomcat instance in eclipse.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, it works now with `<scope>provided</scope>`, but if I want to package it as a war file and run it on a tomcat server, what changes would I have to make then?

Comment: @Chaos You don't from a Maven side. Because of provided scope, maven won't add the jar for that lib when generating a `war`. The whole point of provided is that some container (tomcat) will provide that lib on the classpath when running your application. Make sure your Tomcat server is recent enough to be running servlet 3.0.